# command prompt can run batch file but cmd can NOT

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

i get a simple test.bat:

```
@echo off
echo hello world
pause
```

it can run in command prompt but can't run in cmd.exe.

if i press Win+R and enter "cmd", i can get a cmd.exe, but it can not run batch file:

[cmd.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uu7W.png)

it just get a blank line with no response. i don't know why.

but if i open command prompt in start menu, it can run batch file:

[command prompt in start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEDab.png)

[run batch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnnPQ.png)

also the front setting are different.

here is the properties of command prompt and we can see that it points to the system32/cmd.exe, which is the same path to cmd.

[command prompt properties and source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdgYx.png)

but Why are they different? And how can i run batch file in cmd.exe cause some software need it?

Comment: Please click on __Command Prompt__ and then run `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY HKCU\Console`. There should be output just the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` with lots of registry values which are used by default whenever a console application is executed with no special console settings. Is there output a subkey with its own set of registry values on your computer? The Microsoft developer blog [Understanding Windows Console Host Settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/) should help you understanding the registry key.

Comment: Run in the __Command Prompt__ also `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe cmd`. Is there output `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`? Yes, open __CMD__ and run the same command line. Is there also output `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`? Yes, then run now `cmd /?` and read the brief description about the `AutoRun` registry value. Run now `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun`. There should be output the error message `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.` as this registry value does not exist by Windows default.

Comment: Otherwise look on the output registry value to find out which program respectively installer corrupted the *Windows Command Processor* configuration on your PC and run next `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f` to fix it by deleting the `AutoRun` registry value. Next run `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun` (HKLM instead of HKCU) and if there is not output an error message, open __Command Prompt as administrator__ and run the deletion command line with `HKLM` instead of `HKCU`.

Comment: It looks like you are using Windows 10 22H2 according to the version of executed `cmd.exe`. I use already Windows 11 22H2. Has Windows 10 also in __Settings__ under __Privacy & security__ on left side and __For developers__ on right side an item __Terminal__ with the list options *Let Windows decide* and *Windows Console Host* and *Windows Terminal*? Yes, what happens on selecting *Windows Console Host* and running __CMD__ from __Start__ menu?

Comment: @Mofi sincerely thank you for your help. i run above where and QUERY command, which get the same ERROR mentioned above. In win 10, Default Terminal Application only has "Let Windows decide" and "Windows Console Host", and whatever i choose dosen't change the cmd.

Comment: Okay! What about output of `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY HKCU\Console`? The two console windows are definitely different. The font is definitely different. The number of rows and columns could be identical considering the different fonts. The color settings are definitely identical. That means for me that there must be a subkey under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` which defines settings different or the __Command Prompt__ shortcut has a font setting which is different to the registry values `FaceName` and perhaps also `FontFamily` under key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

Comment: The default font on Windows 11 for console, or more precise __Command Prompt__, is __Cascadia Mono__ which is registered as `FaceName` with value `__DefaultTTFont__`. The default font was `Consolas` for `Console` for Windows 8 and 8.1 and the bitmap OEM font `Terminal` for Windows XP to Windows 7. I suppose a batch file "game" or a bad coded console application changed the font configuration on your PC instead of changing the font just for the console window of the command process/console application.

Comment: @Mofi that's quite convincing for me, but i run this command in CMD and Command Prompt, the outputs are absolutely the same.

Comment: Right click on the title bar of the window with title `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` and click in context menu on __Settings__. There should be on left side __Command Prompt__ in language configured for your account and not in language of the operating system (very strange to see German `Eingabeaufforderung` while all other items on left side are displayed in English) which has on right side __Appearance__ which needs to be expanded to see the options for `Console`.

Comment: i get chcp of 936 in command prompt which means China, but i get 413697 in cmd.exe, is that some errors?

Comment: The Microsoft documentation page [Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) and the Wikipedia page [Code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) do both not list `413697` as code page identifier. The code page identifiers are 16-bit unsigned integer values as far as I know. `413697` looks like a corruption somewhere in your Windows configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helping of @Mofi, the `chcp` of two terminals are different, and the `chcp` of cmd is wrong.

the difference between `command prompt` and `CMD`, they are the same program except some settings are different. there are some points which may help you better understand it.

> When modifying ‘Properties’, changes will be persisted to either the per-Console-application settings in the registry, or to the Windows shortcut file:

> If the application was launched directly (e.g. via the Windows run dialog), changes will be persisted in the per-application storage location mentioned above (#3 in the hierarchy).

> If the application was launched via a Windows shortcut file, changes will be persisted directly into the .lnk file (the fourth item in the hierarchy).
> For Console applications with a shortcut, you can also right-click on the shortcut file itself and choose ‘Properties’ to access the settings dialog.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/ for more details.

So we need to check the settings of registry. you can check command `reg` on https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY HKCU\Console
```

Above command shows the registry values of console application, which should be output just the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` with lots of registry values which are used by default whenever a console application is executed with no special console settings.

or you just WIN+R and enter `regedit` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` to check the  [registry table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T20qY.png).

here if you codepage entry is not corresponding to your region, you can change the value on codepage and the batch file can run properly.

Also you can check the chcp easily by run `chcp` which may get sth like:

```
Active code page: 65001
```

you can chick on the link for what is [chcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp). the output by change code page(chcp) command depends on the country/region configured for the account used to start cmd.exe.

if your code page is proper, you need to check the AutoRun entry. run `cmd /?` to check content about AutoRun. Try run below commands:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```

if you get error like `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.` which means this registry value does not exist by Windows default.

But if you don't get error, looking on the output registry value to find out which program respectively installer corrupted the Windows Command Processor configuration on your PC and run next

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```

to fix it by deleting the AutoRun registry value.

otherwise you need to check the registry carefully since i fix it by change the codepage entry on registry.

for more details please check the comments and again thx the helping of @Mofi !!